# nginx server_name config for proxy

Tags: nginx

Needed to route

- 127.0.0.1 to http://frontend  [ works ]
- 127.0.0.1/backend to http://backend [ does not work ]

Currently, http://backend opens backend , however I needed to open backend by 127.0.0.1/backend URL instead

What is missing in below nginx conf ?

nginx - vhost.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name frontend;

    root /app/frontend/web;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name backend;

    root /app/backend/web;
    index index.php index.html;


    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

hosts file as below -

```
127.0.0.1 frontend
127.0.0.1 backend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server { 
  server_name backend;

location / {
# app1 reverse proxy follow
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
  }
}
```

This should work ! 
also SEE :

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/